# MS Access: Query to list number of files in a series of folders

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have folders labeled by their keyfield, so 1, 2, ... 999, 1000. located in currentproject.path\RecordFiles\KeyFieldHere so like currentproject.path\RecordFiles\917.

I want to run a query that will count how many files are in each folder. I know this can be done with the DIR function through visual basic, but I can't seem to run it through a SQL query.

I've tried using [this function](https://www.devhut.net/2012/07/06/vba-count-files-in-folderdirectory/) in a SQL equation, so Expr1: [FlrFileCount("Y:\Education\Databases\RecordFiles\")] as one of the fields just to see if it can work, but it prompts me for a value and then returns nothing.

EDIT: I tried an approach using the FlrFileCount function in a continuous form, and it does work, BUT... I get an error after every single line. I have a field in a continuous form of =FlrFileCount([currentproject].[path] & "\recordfiles\" & [ID]), but when I run the form I get an error "Error 76, Error source: FlrFileCount, Error description: Path not found." Which is crazy because IT WORKS, it properly lists the number of files in the folder for each record.

I just need to get this functionality over into a SQL query so I can pull that data for mail merges.

I currently have something similar in a form. The form has an onload property to run a module [(Link here)](http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-59.html) to create a list of all the files in the relevant folder to that record, and then I have another field that just counts the number of entries in the list. However a list can't be a value in a SQL query, so I don't think that code will help.

Comment: Can you explain how this is being used? I’m not sure why SQL has to be involved, this seems like VBA all the way

Comment: The idea is that certain files need to be uploaded to certain folders, and I want a query that will check all of the relevant folders and let me know which ones do and do not have a file uploaded. This will be used for automated reminders. I am close to getting the function working in visual basic in a form, but I can't pull data OUT of a form like that.

Comment: Try `=FlrFileCount(Currentproject.Path & "\recordfiles\" & [ID])`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim Williams, the answer was to put

=FlrFileCount(Currentproject.Path & "\recordfiles\" & [ID])

It seems the [currentproject].[path] part was where the error was. What's confusing is that in other places, MS Access adds the extra [] around currentproject and path, and I don't know why.

Thank you so much for your help! Now to the tricky part: Implementing a proper naming scheme by program ID across a sharepoint so that the relevant folder can be opened consistently even when program names change.